# Generating Rails Embed using data attribute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, embed

I would like to create a content feed using Rails that can be embedded into another person's site, but am trying to do so in a specific way.

I would like the embed code to look something like the following:

```
<script src="//domain.com/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="//domain.com/embed.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<ul class="content-feed" data-feed-id="someID"></ul>
```

Instead of having the parameter for the feed in the url like: http://domain.com/embed/1.js , then http://domain.com/embed/2.js for two separate feeds for example.

I have a couple reasons for this, such as it makes it easy to have one js and one css file/link for every user.

One of the problems I see is that I would like to be able to save changes to how the feed is generated for that specific content feed in the user's dashboard without re-embedding the code, such as different sources or layouts.

It'd very helpful if anyone could give general direction or tell me how I might go about this process. At the moment, the feeds are simply generated on a page within my web application and that is the only place they can be seen.

Comment: you can construct the Javascript dynamically using ERB. Give the file an `.js.erb` extension.

Comment: So then the data-feed-id would have to be passed to the server in an ajax call and then used to return the correct attributes? Or is there an easier way than this?